# a nonconstant polynomial $f \in \mathbf{Z}[t]$ such that $|f(n)|$ is a power of some prime number (depending on $n$), for every $n \in \mathbf{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Does there exist a nonconstant polynomial $f \in \mathbf{Z}[t]$ such
that $|f(n)|$ is a power of some prime number (depending on $n$), for
every $n \in \mathbf{Z}$?

**My Attempt**: We know that there is no polynomial with integer coefficient which is generate only prime number but What about in this case. Give some hints.

Comment: If $p| f(a)$ then what can you say of $f(a+pn)$ ?

Comment: Did you at least look for a reference for the statement of your so-called "attempt", and read the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Remark:

If this holds, then it holds for a single prime $p$ for all $n$.  To see this:

Suppose $p,q$ are distinct primes such that $p\,|\,f(a)$ and $q$ divides $f(b)$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb N$.

Then $$a'\equiv a \pmod p\implies f(a')\equiv 0\pmod p$$
with a similar claim for $q,b$.

However, since $p\neq q$ we can solve $$qk\equiv (a-b)\pmod p$$ for $k$ and, with that $k$ we see that both $p,q$ divide $f(b+qk)$.

Example:  taking $f(n)=n^2+n+1$ we see that $3\,|\,f(1)$ and $7\,|\,f(2)$.  We solve $7k\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ to get $k=2$ and remark that $21$ divides $f(2+7\times 2)=f(16)$

Hence you are down to the case where there is only a single prime $p$.

To rule out the case of a single prime $p$, note that the constant term can not be $0$ (if it were, then we'd get $n\,|\,f(n)$ which is clearly not possible).  Let $f(0)=p^k$.  Then $f(p^j)$ can not be divisible by $p^{k+1}$ if $j>k$.  But then there are only finitely many values $f(p^j)$ might have, and that is not possible, since a polynomial of degree $d$ can take each given value no more than $d$ times.

And we are done.

Comment: Thanku very much, very nice.