# Nonconstant polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $f(0)=1$, then there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)$ is divisible by 2021 primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm working on a problem which is stated as follows :

> Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a nonconstant polynomial with $f(0)=1$. Then, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(n)$ is divisible by $2021$ (distinct) primes.

I have a hint which says that I can use the Chinese remainder theorem. I suppose $2021$ is just an arbitrary number and that this holds for all natural numbers. I know that for all primes $p$, it is true that $f(0) \equiv 1 \pmod  p$. If $n$ is the product of these primes, I know that $f(0)\equiv 1 \pmod  n$. But I don't see how I can conclude something about $f(n)$ from here?

Comment: For a related question see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653968/a-nonconstant-polynomial-f-in-mathbfzt-such-that-fn-is-a-power-of).

Comment: If $f(x)$ is such a polynomial then $f(n)$ does not attaint all the integers when $n$ is an rational integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you need values of $p$ such that $p$ is *dividing* a value like $f(r)$. Even if $f(0) \equiv 1\mod p$, this in no way helps find a value $r$ such that $p$ divides $f(r)$.

The idea is that to find such values of $r$, one needs to prove an existence result rather than explicitly construct such numbers. Indeed, as a consequence of the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019538/primes-dividing-a-polynomial), the set of primes dividing at least one element of $f(\mathbb N) = \{f(n) : n \in \mathbb N\}$ is an infinite set. The answer of Andre Nicolas is elementary enough and shows the desired result by contradiction.

Pick the first $2021$ such distinct primes $p_1,\ldots,p_{2021}$ which divide some element of $f(\mathbb N)$. Let $r_i \in \mathbb N$ be such that $p_i | f(r_i)$.

As a consequence of the fact that $x-y | f(x)-f(y)$ for any $x,y\in \mathbb Z$, we know that for any $i=1,2,\ldots,2021$ and $k \in \mathbb N$, $$kp_i|f(r_i+kp_i)-f(r_i) \implies p_i |f(r_i+kp_i)$$

It's sufficient, at this point of time, to assert the existence of $M \in \mathbb N$  such that $$
M \equiv r_i \pmod{p_i}, i=1,2,\ldots,2021.
$$
This follows from the Chinese remainder theorem since the primes $p_i$ are distinct and hence coprime to each other. The value $f(M)$ is divisible by each of $p_i,i=1,2,\ldots,2021$ and provides the desired conclusion.

Three remarks :

- $f(0)=1$ is not important, it's the non-constant nature of $f$ that matters.
- $2021$ is an arbitrary number, because I could pick as many $p_i,r_i$ as necessary and play the same game.
- It is not possible to fix the values of $p_i$ before seeing what the polynomial is. For example, if $f(x)=6x+1$ then $f(n)$ is never going to be divisible by $3$. That's why one can only discover the $p_i$ above abstractly.

Comment: @Oopsilon You're welcome!